# AUTOSAR equivalent for "Hello World!"?

Tags: autosar

I'm totally new to AUTOSAR and Arctic Studio. I have read the documentation available on www.autosar.org and now I would like to start playing around, understanding and writing some code.

I also found that only open source free development environment available for AUTOSAR platform is Arctic Studio (please correct me if I'm wrong). So I downloaded and installed it. I followed all the steps at `http://212.181.18.149/wiki/Quick-start_Tutorial` but unfortunately my build was not error-free.

I read example codes given in the 'examples' folder but didn't exactly get what happening or how to get started with writing even a simple code.

I was wondering if anyone could point me a direction to create a "Hello World" equivalent for AUTOSAR.

Answer (score 3):

AUTOSAR is a platform configurable based in layers.

You need the MCAL layer from the semiconductor company. The BSW+RTE layer created by your company/university or maybe some free plus the RTOS, then you integrate all for your uC, and create your "Hello World" in the APP layer, in some SWC to "print/send/show" the "Hello world" message.

If you don't have RTE or APP layer, you can create a CDD to execute your "Hello World".

The easiest way should be only using the MCAL: put the "hello world" in the main function, just integrate/configure the MCAL, (and the Startup). Check it with the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a hello world equivalent in Autosar won't help you to familar with the concept.

you require the following things to get a know how about Autosar.

1)you need the MCAL(microcontroller layer),BSW and a simple application in the system.Non autosar component which can be included as Complex device driver is optional.

2)Create a sample application which sends a data 1 or 0 from a swc to any IO driver(preferable DIO)
depending on this you turn an LED on or off based on the corresponding registers

Also check for the supported boards on the Arcore site.

Commasso also provides an open source tool for Autosar but only to its members

Answer (score 1):

Arctic Core supports about a dosen different development boards which are listed in [boards/](http://my.arccore.com/hg/arc-stable/file/9c57d86f66be/boards) folder. If you have one of these, you can actually build and run a small project which prints "Hello world" over the UART or blinks a LED.

Answer (score 1):

Walk through this [tutorial and introduction to AUTOSAR](https://elearning.vector.com/vl_autosar_introduction_en.html) by one of the biggest 3rd party provides, Vector Informatik GmbH.

The typical "Hello world" in the Embedded and Electronics world would be a blinking LED. Such examples exist for AUTOSAR too, however as has been pointed out you need several tools, libraries, packages, hardware to make this happen. Another way of "Hello world" in AUTOSAR could be a CAN message which you send on the bus, which is a key feature of every vehicle ECU being able to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

There is another version of open source AUTOSAR platform available, How ever it is not completely free, Check this out

https://www.comasso.org/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this question really indicate that you are not much aware of AUTOSAR, as per AUTOSAR there is no UART module either.. of course blinking a LED is possible using DIO module along with PORT module.

I will try to explain as much as I can, please correct me if I am wrong and I am working in AUTOSAR development from last 5 years..

1. AUTOSAR is a collection of different requirement for developing ECU's in automotive industry.
2. Its some what open to all also, you can get all latest requirement on it from http://www.autosar.org/
3. Its total number of components or modules depends on your application and ECU.
4. Its architecture is in such a way that you can develope any one or few module or component and can use it with any other AUTOSAT compatible module / components.   ( if both designed for same AUTOSAR major versions).

BR
Jerry James